# Adding an attribute to keep track of subscribers numbers - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have an attribute on `Subscriber` called `mug_number` its data type is an integer. I have a page where a person can sign up to be a Subscriber, Whenever a person signs up I want this number to increment by 1 so that in the index I can see what number belongs to each person. I'll post code for clarity.

SUBSCRIBER CONTROLLER:

```
  class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  def index
    @search = Subscriber.search(params[:q])
    @subscriber = @search.result
    @search.build_condition if @search.conditions.empty?
    @search.build_sort if @search.sorts.empty?
  end

  def new
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
  end

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.create(subscriber_params)
    if @subscriber.save
      flash[:notice] = "Subscriber Has Been Successfully Created"
      redirect_to new_subscriber_path(:subscriber)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

SCHEMA:

```
 create_table "subscribers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "phone_number"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "visit"
    t.integer  "mug_number"
  end
```

As you can see in the schema I have the `mug_number` attribute on `Subscriber`

Right now I'm trying to add a hidden_field for the form but I don't think that the right implementation?

FORM:

```
 <%= form_for @subscriber do |form| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>
      <%= form.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "First Name", class: "text_field" %>
      </p>
      <p>
      <%= form.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "Last Name", class: "text_field" %>
      </p>
      <p>
       <%= form.text_field :phone_number, placeholder: "phone", class: "text_field" %>
      </p>
      <p>
      <%= form.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email", class: "text_field" %>
      </p>
      <%= form.hidden_field :mug_number %>
    </div>
    <%= form.submit "Sign Up", class: "btn" %>
  <% end %>
```

This should be an easy story but for some reason I can't seem to figure it out? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need a hidden field because you don't want to generate the number until it's time to save the record.

A `before_create` callback on the `Subscriber` model should do.

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :generate_mug_number

private

  def generate_mug_number
    last_number = Subscriber.maximum(:mug_number) || 0
    self.mug_number = last_number + 1
  end
end
```

Comment: I really like this idea but when I tried to implement it didn't work? is there anything else I need to know?

Comment: everything worked as before. Like when I signed a person up it didn't place a count on mug_number

Comment: Not sure what it could be. I have similar logic running to create sequential invoice numbers in one of our apps.